# Draggable widget feedbackOffset not working

Tags: flutter

I have the following code(Row widget with a Draggable), and the text widget is always dragged from upper left corner of the cell.

I am looking for a text without yellow underlines and dragged from the center of the cell - do you know how?

[image]

```
Widget buildContainer(String text) {
  return Container(color: Colors.white, child: Center(child: Text(text)));
}

Widget createExpandedRow(List<String> listRow) {
  return Expanded(
      child: Row(
          children: listRow
              .map((e) => Expanded(
                  child: Draggable(
                      data: "data",
                      feedbackOffset: const Offset(200, 200),
                      feedback: buildContainer(e),
                      child: buildContainer(e)
                  )))
              .toList()));
}
```